# Find empty rows in csv file and track the row number in a collection

Tags: c#, csv, csvhelper

How do I get the row number of a record when all the fields are empty in a CSV file read using [CSVHelper](https://github.com/joshclose/csvhelper)?

```
reader.Configuration.SkipEmptyRecords = true;

reader.GetRecords<OrderDetails>().ToList();
```

I am using the configuration to skip the empty records as of now but I need to make a note of the row id?

Comment: what did you try?

Comment: `reader.Configuration.SkipEmptyRecords = true;`
`reader.GetRecords<OrderDetails>().ToList();`
I am using the configuration to skip the empty records as of now but I need to make a note of the row id ?

Comment: thats almost a "whats your fave colour" - answer "adam" .. ok, show your code, show how youve stored it, and show what you did to try and find row numbers with empty data

Comment: If you want to track empty rows you shouldn't *skip* them. You should handle them using the appropriate method. Unfortunately CSVHelper changes major versions every other week, with callbacks appearing and disappearing all the time. Which version did you use?

Comment: Another option is to use `GetRecord` instead of `GetRecords` and check the returned object. There may not be a combination of skip or error callbacks that will return what you want. Again, you should specify the version.

Comment: CSVHelper 2.16.3 is what I'm currently using

Comment: @VijayakumarNatarajan the current version is 6.1.0, where the property is renamed to IgnoreBlankLines